# Merge an interface from one subgraph with a type from another subgraph using GQL Stitching

Tags: graphql, graphql-federation

I have 2 services in my system, which both have their own subgraphs.

**Product Service**, which is "smart" i.e. knows about different product types and **Suggestions Service** which is rather "dumb" i.e. only knows that there are some products, but nothing about specific types. So the 2 subgraphs look something like the following:

**Product Service**

```js
interface Product {
   id: String!
   name: String!
}

type FoodProduct implements Product {
  id: String!
  name: String!
  expiryDate: String!
}

type ToolProduct implements Product {
  id: String!
  name: String!
  durabilityRating: Float!
}

type Query {
  products: [Product]
  productById(id: String!): Product
}
```

**Suggestions Service**

```js
type Product {
   id: String!
   similarProducts: [Product]
}

type Query {
  similarProducts(productId: String!): [Product]
}
```

I need to keep the **Suggestions Service** "dumb" also in the future i.e. when new Product types are added in the **Product Service**, I do not have to change anything on the **Suggestions Service**.

Now when I query the gateway / supergraph, I would need to be able to run a query like this:

```js
query Products {
  products {
    id
    name
    ... on FoodProduct {
      expiryDate
      similarProducts {
        id
        name
        ... on FoodProduct {
          expiryDate
        }
      }
    }
    ... on ToolProduct {
      durabilityRating
      similarProducts {
        id
        name
        ... on ToolProduct {
          durabilityRating
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone have ideas how I could achieve this using Stitching?

I have used Apollo Federation with the @interfaceObject directive (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/federation/federated-types/interfaces/) which works very well in that situation actually, but unfortunately because of some other reasons, we need to move away from using Apollo Federation.

I also have experimented with GQL Fusion (https://chillicream.com/blog/2023/08/15/graphql-fusion), but it seem that they are not yet at this point, where such use case can be implemented.

Now looking into Stitching options (https://the-guild.dev/graphql/stitching/docs), but have not found any example that would support my use case... maybe I am just not seeing it right now, thus asking for some help / ideas